# How to include variables in javascripts strings

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the script as as follows:
I want to inclde th index value as shown below.  How can I do that? With my actual code,I am having error

```
for(var index = 1; index < 6; index++){

   $("#myTable thead td:nth-child(index + 2).html("here");

}
```

Comment: Your example is missing a bracket. Are you sure thats your code?

Comment: you code does not work as you are missing a close bracket for one reason... @Curt has the right answer

Comment: Your syntax is missing a parenteses, but I suppose you can just do this within the html function: html(var + "<br/>") ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do:

```
for(var index = 1; index < 6; index++){
   var nthchild = index+2;
   $("#myTable thead td:nth-child("+nthchild+")").html(index);
}
```

Comment: @Ash Burlaczenko I think it got edited (not that I downvoted)

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate string, and sorted your syntax error:

```
  for(var index = 1; index < 6; index++)
  {    
      $("#myTable thead td:nth-child(" + (index+2) + ")").html('here');
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to write:

```
for(var index = 1; index < 6; index++) {
    $("#myTable thead td:nth-child("+(index+2)+")").html("here");
}
```